# How do I pass data from Ember Power Select?

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm a beginner at Ember so I'm probably missing something very simple.

I have a form that contains a Ember input helpers for text input and [Ember Power Select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/action-handling) components for choosing things from a dropdown.

The form input works and the action successfully saves the values from the text inputs with an action helper. However, the Ember Power Selects don't send any values.

Component.hbs

```
 {{#power-select
    selected=telaviv
    class="form-dropdown"
    options=cities
    onchange=(action "chooseCity")
    as |city|}}
  {{city}}
{{/power-select}}
```

Component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    cities: ['Tel Aviv', 'Jerusalem', 'Haifa', 'Be\'er Sheva', 'Givat Shmuel'],
    telaviv: 'Tel Aviv',

    actions: {
      chooseCity(city) {
        this.set('telaviv', city);
        // this.calculateRoute();
        // this.updatePrice();
      }
    }
  });
```

All the form components are nested inside another component.

HBS:

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="new-date-form-container col-md-8">
      I took a date to a {{type-dropdown}}
      called
      {{input dropdownClass="slide-fade"
        type="text"
        class="form-textbox"
        placeholder="Place"
        value=place
        maxlength=30}}
      <br>
      <br>
      It was in
      {{city-dropdown}}
      <br>
      <br>
      and the date cost about
      {{price-dropdown}}
      I'd describe the place as
      {{atmosphere-dropdown}}
      so it works for
      {{input
        type="text"
        class="form-textbox"
        placeholder="Suitable for"
        value=suitablefor
        maxlength=20}}
      <br>
      <br>
      Here's an insider tip:
      {{input
        type="text"
        class="form-textbox"
        placeholder="Pro Tip"
        value=protip
        maxlength=70}}
      <br>
      <br>
      Their website is:
      {{input
        type="text"
        class="form-textbox"
        placeholder="Website"
        value=website}}
      <br>
      <br>
      It looks like this:
      {{input
        type="text"
        class="form-textbox"
        placeholder="Image"
        value=imageurl}}
      <br>
      <button {{action 'savedate' date}} class="submitbutton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

And its JS:

```
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
      savedate: function() {
          var newdate = this.get('store').createRecord('date', {
              imageurl: this.get('imageurl'),
              place: this.get('place'),
              type: this.get('type'),
              city: this.get('city'),
              price: this.get('price'),
              atmosphere: this.get('atmosphere'),
              suitablefor: this.get('suitablefor'),
              protip: this.get('protip'),
              website: this.get('website')
          });
var component = this;
          newdate.save().then(function() {
            alert('Date submission successful');
            component.setProperties({
                imageurl: '',
                place: '',
                type: '',
                city: '',
                price: '',
                atmosphere: '',
                suitablefor: '',
                protip: '',
                website: ''
            });
          }, function() {
            // handle error (show error message, retry, etc.)
            alert('Please try again');
          });

      }
  }
});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not related to Ember Power Select itself.

In your example, the `{{city-dropdown}}` component is isolated. The component is working but is making local changes to that component. It is setting the value value of the property names `telaviv` (weird name since the `telaviv` property might contain the "Jerusalem" string).

You should pass some data to that component (`{{city-dropdown city=city}}`) and make EPS change that value in the `onchange` action.

Comment: An answer from the creator himself! Thanks so much. Everything works perfectly now.
Thanks for creating this addon!

Comment: One more question actually. How do I make the field required?